# D+R: How many randomized trials to determine the D value?

Tags: random-variable, randomized-tests

I have an unknown fixed integer D.  N binary random variables R were added to D.

In each randomized trial we can observe the sum D+R. But we don't know D and we don't know the R's outcome in each trial. We only know the sum.

R is a uniformly distributed random 0/1 value.  N random values were added to D.
So you can assume that on average N random values add up to N/2.

How many trials of D+R values I need to examine before I can predict the D value with some confidence?

Hope my question made sense.  I didn't know how else to explain it.

Comment: You describe R as binary then you describe R as uniformly distributed. You also refer to R as a single observation, then as the sum of N observations. You don't say if they are independent. Can you please clean up the notation?

Comment: Sorry I am not a statistician. Please help me clean it up.   How about this "R is a random variable with 0 or 1 outcome and probability of a 0 is 0.5.  R is observed N times.  Each observation is independent of the others."    Or like this "R is a fair coin with 0 and 1 faces. It is flipped N times.  Sum face values are added to D.  We know the sum.  But we don't know the N values of R.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law is what I need, I think